# Jquery Mobile - popup before close event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to run few checks (this code is working) when close event is triggered, and prevent popup from closing, if any error is found (and show the message).

It seems that JQM doesn't have before close event (or something similar). Is it possible to do this?

This is the HTML code for the popup:

```
<div id="divPropertyPopup"
     class="ui-content form-horizontal"
     data-role="popup"
     data-overlay-theme="a"
     data-dismissible="false"
     style="min-width:30em; padding: 1em;">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext"
       class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <h4>Edit Optional Field Properties</h4>

    <div id="view_edit" data-role="fieldcontain" class="hidden">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label style="padding: 0 !important; text-align: left !important;" class="preview_label"
                 for="functionmode">Form Function Mode</label>

          <select class="form-control" id="functionmode" title="Form Function Mode">
            <option value="edit">Edit Mode</option>
            <option value="view">View Mode</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="descriptionRow">
        <label class="preview_label"
               for="property_desc">Description</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="fieldproperty"
               id="property_desc"
               title="Description"/>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label class="preview_label"
               for="property_inst">Instructions</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="fieldproperty"
               id="property_inst"
               title="Instructions"/>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label class="preview_label"
               for="property_keyw">Keywords</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="fieldproperty"
               id="property_keyw"
               title="Keywords - Separated by commas"/>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">

        <label class="preview_label"
               for="property_unique"
               style="width: 100%; text-align: left">Unique Field Identifier</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="fieldproperty"
               id="property_unique"
               title="Unique Field Identifier - Separated by commas"/>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="mandatoryRow">
        <label style="padding: 0 !important;" class="preview_label"
               for="property_mand">Mandatory</label>
        <input type="checkbox"
               class="fieldproperty form-control"
               id="property_mand"
               title="Mandatory Status"/>
    </div>


    <div class="row" id="limitsRow">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label class="preview_label"
                       for="property_min">Min</label>
                <input type="text"
                       class="fieldproperty"
                       id="property_min"
                       title="Minimum Value"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label class="preview_label"
                       for="property_max">Max</label>
                <input type="text"
                       class="fieldproperty"
                       id="property_max"
                       title="Maximum Value"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- popup -->
```

Comment: You don't need a special event for this. Remove `data-rel="back"` to have control over close button. Once clicked, run your validation code and then close it `.popup("close")` or show error message.

Comment: something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/uLjsp2rn/1/